# console.log() output appears to be cached

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I'm making the following call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/charts/' + empID + '/' + chartID + '.json?' + new Date().getTime(),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    chart = Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, options);
  }
});
```

As you can see, when I get the data back, I pass it along to the chartist-js library and I do all sorts of manipulations there, but the first thing I do is log the data to the console.

This is the data returned from a .json file

```
{
  "labels": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "Autonomy",
      "meta": [4,2,7,3,9,1],
      "data": [1,2,null,null,null,10]
    }
  ]
}
```

But the output to the console is:

```
{
  "labels": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6"
  ],
  "series": [
    [
      1,
      2,
      4,
      6,
      8,
      10
    ]
  ]
}
```

Notice that the `null` values in `series[0].data` are different and the entire object has been flattened to just the data. When I pass the returned data to Chartist, I do all sorts of manipulation, including averaging null values against the rest of the data. But, that shouldn't be printing here in the console? It hasn't even been passed in yet.

Any thoughts about what might be going on?

Notice that I'm adding a timestamp to my request as an attempt at cache busting. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: isn't the list method on Chartist changing your values?

Comment: If you copy the parsed URL and enter it on the browser, do you get the JSON you referred to? Also, did you debug it and is that the line that's outputting that result?

Comment: you see actual object state at the moment, when you expand it in the console. You just change it before expand.

Comment: @Matheus208 Yes, if I go to the URL, the JSON is what I expect to see. And yes, I've debugged it to death to guarantee that the line prior to passing the data to chartist is the one I'm looking at

Comment: try to `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)))`. This will clone all data and it will not to change with original `data` object.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Is there a little blue `i` next to the object in the console?  That means something like "the object will be re-evaluated when it's expanded" - ie it could have changed since it was logged.

Comment: Sweet fancy Moses, yes. Blue icon: "Object value at left was snapshotted when logged, value below was evaluated just now." Wow that's annoying. Thanks so much for helping me realize I'm not insane!

Comment: Is there any way to disable this?